# Aggregation function with condition in select statement using SQL Server 2008

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have following table:

```
create table test
(
 cola integer
)
```

With some data:

```
cola
-------
0
1
0
2
0
3
0
4
0
5
```

Here I need to `count` number of zero's presents in the `cola`, and also want to sum number of other values which are greater than 0, like `sum(1,2,3,4,5)` .

My bad try:

```
select count(cola) as zeros ,sum(cola) as others
from test
where cola = 0 and cola > 0;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want conditional aggregation:

```
select sum(case when cola = 0 then 1 else 0 end) as zeros,
       sum(case when cola > 0 then cola else 0 end) as others
from test;
```

Strictly speaking, the second conditional is not needed, assuming the values are never negative:

```
select sum(case when cola = 0 then 1 else 0 end) as zeros,
       sum(cola) as others
from test;
```

Answer (score 0):

this query will count number of zero's presents in the cola, and also sum number of other values which are greater than 0, like sum(1,2,3,4,5)

**Answer:**

```
select 
count (case when cola=0 then cola end) as Zeros,
sum (case when cola>0 then cola end) as otherthanzeroes
from test;
```